# select new (JPQL Constructor Expression) in jpa/hibernate causes "lazy" loading for each row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

Recently I found no obvious behaviour when using ['select new/constructor expression'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor)  in jpa/hibernate. It uses kind of lazy loading for each entity in each row in result set what is not efficient.

### Test example

```
@Value
public class PojoTuple {
    Entity1 e1;
    Entity2 e2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1", schema = DEFAULT_DATABASE_SCHEMA)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "field1", nullable = false)
    private String field1;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2", schema = DEFAULT_DATABASE_SCHEMA)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "fkentity1", nullable = false)
    private String entity1Id;

    @Column(name = "field2", nullable = false)
    private String field2;
}

create table entity1
(
    id     varchar2(22 char) not null primary key,
    field1 varchar2(50 char) not null
);

create table entity2
(
    id        varchar2(22 char) not null primary key,
    fkentity1 varchar2(22 char) not null,
    field2    varchar2(50 char) not null

);

insert into entity1 (id, field1) values ('10', 'anyvalue1');
insert into entity1 (id, field1) values ('11', 'anyvalue2');

insert into entity2 (id, fkentity1, field2) VALUES ('20', '10', 'anyvalue3');
insert into entity2 (id, fkentity1, field2) VALUES ('21', '11', 'anyvalue4');
```

### First case

we issue a query using *select new* technique:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select new my.package.PojoTuple(e1, e2) " +
                                        "from Entity1 e1 " +
                                        "join Entity2 e2 on e1.id=e2.entity1Id ");
query.getResultList();
```

This issues one query to fetch **only ids** of e1 and e2 and then more queries to fetch e1, e2 by id one by one for each row in result set:

> Query:["select entity1x0_.id as col_0_0_, entity2x1_.id as col_1_0_
> from schema.entity1 entity1x0_ inner join schema.entity2 entity2x1_ on
> (entity1x0_.id=entity2x1_.fkentity1)"]
>
> Query:["select entity1x0_.id as id1_1_0_, entity1x0_.field1 as
> field2_1_0_ from schema.entity1 entity1x0_ where entity1x0_.id=?"]
> Params:[(10)]
>
> Query:["select entity2x0_.id as id1_2_0_, entity2x0_.fkentity1 as
> fkentity2_2_0_, entity2x0_.field2 as field3_2_0_ from schema.entity2
> entity2x0_ where entity2x0_.id=?"] Params:[(20)]
>
> Query:["select entity1x0_.id as id1_1_0_, entity1x0_.field1 as
> field2_1_0_ from schema.entity1 entity1x0_ where entity1x0_.id=?"]
> Params:[(11)]
>
> Query:["select entity2x0_.id as id1_2_0_, entity2x0_.fkentity1 as
> fkentity2_2_0_, entity2x0_.field2 as field3_2_0_ from schema.entity2
> entity2x0_ where entity2x0_.id=?"] Params:[(21)]

### Second case

Whereas rewriting sample from above to:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select e1, e2 " +
                                        "from Entity1 e1 " +
                                        "join Entity2 e2 on e1.id=e2.entity1Id ");

query.getResultList();
```

Issues exactly one query to database with all required fields selected:

> Query:["select entity1x0_.id as id1_1_0_, entity2x1_.id as id1_2_1_,
> entity1x0_.field1 as field2_1_0_, entity2x1_.fkentity1 as
> fkentity2_2_1_, entity2x1_.field2 as field3_2_1_ from schema.entity1
> entity1x0_ inner join schema.entity2 entity2x1_ on
> (entity1x0_.id=entity2x1_.fkentity1)"]
> Params:[()]

### Question

From my perspective there is no big difference how these two queries should be performed. First case issues many queries that I do not expect what is highly inefficient. Second case works as expected issuing exactly one query to database. Is this a bug, suboptimal solution or some hidden feature that I can not see?

Environment
hibernate-core: 5.6.9.Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found partial explanation from the most authoritative source of knowledge about hibernate I know - Vlad Mihalcea: [Paragraph: Returning an entity in a DTO projection](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/)

> However, there might be use cases when you want to select an entity inside your DTO projection.
> (...)
>
> When you execute a JPQL query like this one:
>
> ```
> List<PersonAndCountryDTO> personAndAddressDTOs = entityManager.createQuery(
> "select new " +
> "   com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.dto.PersonAndCountryDTO(" +
> "       p, " +
> "       c.name" +
> "   ) " +
> "from Person p " +
> "join Country c on p.locale = c.locale " +
> "order by p.id", PersonAndCountryDTO.class) .getResultList();
> ```
>
> Hibernate generates the following SQL queries:
>
> ```
> SELECT p.id AS col_0_0_,
>    c.name AS col_1_0_ FROM   Person p INNER JOIN
>    Country c ON
>    ( p.locale = c.locale ) ORDER BY
>    p.id   
>
> SELECT p.id AS id1_1_0_,
>    p.locale AS locale2_1_0_,
>    p.name AS name3_1_0_ FROM   Person p WHERE  p.id = 3   
>
> SELECT p.id AS id1_1_0_,
>    p.locale AS locale2_1_0_,
>    p.name AS name3_1_0_ FROM   Person p WHERE  p.id = 4
> ```
>
> The Hibernate 5.2 implementation of the DTO projection cannot
> materialize the DTO projection from the ResultSet without executing a
> secondary query. However, this is very bad to performance since it can
> lead to N+1 query issues.
>
> This HQL limitation has been discussed, and Hibernate 6.0 new SQM parser might address this issue, so stay tuned!

So to summarize:

1. Behaviour I asked about is known to hibernate developers and there is a hope it will be fixed.
2. As for now one has to know that extracting complete, managed entities with constructor expression is completely fine as a design, but with hibernate 5.x can lead to non optimal solution due to many queries issued by hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You should not return entities in objects created with the constructor expression. That's not the intention of this feature and that's also the reason why it loads the data with many queries.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-new

Comment: I see no point in your answer. OP shows an example where a `PojoTuple` is returned in query, and it is not an entity, it's just a POJO. I presume that this is a bug in Hibernate, as I would expect exactly the same behavior of both queries. Docs that you point to states: "The select new construct packages the query results into a user-written Java class instead of an array." so it is exactly designed for this purpose, at least according to the docs.

Comment: The point is that both Entities in PojoTuple will be in the state "managed" after the query. That means depending on the transaction and persistence context the entity are editable and changes will be made to the database on transaction commit

Comment: No they won't be managed. Quote form docs:
"This class does not need to be mapped or annotated in any way.

Even if the class is an entity class, the resulting instances are not managed entities and are not associated with the session."

Comment: Simon, first of all thank you very much for your interest in help. But still it is not clear why this feature *"should not be used this way"* and why *"it is no the intention of this feature"*. The documentation you provided nowhere prohibits such usage, nowhere warns about consequences of such usage, but simply states that *"The select new construct packages the query results into a user-written Java class instead of an array."* So I would consider two methods equal and it does not explain such difference in behaviour.

Comment: Simon, I have just read your comment about entities in PojoTuple being in manageable state. But I would expect than putting them into array (second case) will also fetch them in manageable state. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understood that you state that PojoTuple will be in managed state. It's a good question in what state entities will be, possibly managed, however this should not affect how query is executed. When the query is executed without `new` it also selects both entities, but it's done in one query.

Comment: @Rafi They will be managed!

Comment: @mkobylarz Sure in both cases they are managed. Maybe we should start with the question why you want to load to entities that way

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sure we can talk about my reason to load objects this way (this even may be quite informative for me), but I don't think whole world is really interested in what I am doing and this will for sure make our conversation drift somewhere far from the main goal of this question which is why quite similar cases are handled by hibernate differently for whatever reason it is used.